# How to call time on click of button

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery timer that start on init function using this script

```
var Example1 = new(function () {
    var $stopwatch, // Stopwatch element on the page
        incrementTime = 70, // Timer speed in milliseconds
        currentTime = 0, // Current time in hundredths of a second
        updateTimer = function () {
            $stopwatch.html(formatTime(currentTime));
            currentTime += incrementTime / 10;
        },
        init = function () {
            $stopwatch = $('#stopwatch');
            Example1.Timer = $.timer(updateTimer, incrementTime, true);
        };
    this.resetStopwatch = function () {
        currentTime = 0;
        this.Timer.stop().once();
    };
    $(init);
});
```

I want to start time when user click on button 
I am using example 1 stop watch 
http://jchavannes.com/jquery-timer/demo

I want it to be work when user clik on other button except on page load

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery `click` event:

```
$('button').click(function(){
   var $stopwatch,
   incrementTime,
   /* */
});
```